# React-native audio waveform

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, waveform

I have recorder audio and I want to show waveform like below image. Is there any solution or library for waveform? I am recording audio using `react-native-audio-recorder-player` and using `react-native-fs` storing in local storage.

[Figma design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8sMO.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.